# Why does this loop not run properly

Tags: java, loops

I am suppose to write a java program where I ask user how many math questions they want to answer and generate random questions based on their answer using any loop of choice and keep a count of how many they answered correct. I got it to generate the random math problem, but it only does it once it seems to be skipping the loop. Can anyone help?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class MathQuiz {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random obj = new Random();
        int num1 = obj.nextInt(10);
        int num2 = obj.nextInt(10);
        int rand = num1 + num2;
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many problems would you like to solve?");
        int ans = Integer.parseInt(response); // answer from question
        String result= null;
        int times = input.nextInt();
        int counter = 0; //counts total math problems

        while (counter != ans){
            counter++;
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1 + "+" +num2);
            if (ans == rand){
                result= "Correct";
            }else {
                result= "Incorrect";
            }
        }   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, );

        }
}
```

Comment: The code has at least one syntax error. Try to simply copy and paste it (properly formatted) into the question from the source file.

Comment: The code mixes terminal input (from `System.in`) with GUI input (`showInputDialog`). This can't work.

Comment: You seem to be using `ans` for two different things, and getting confused between the two uses.  Also, when you ask the problem, you're not assigning the user's answer to any variable.  You'll want to do this, so you can check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems in your code:
You are not displaying the result after you compute the value.
Not generating the random numbers every time.

```
    public class MathQuiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many problems would you like to solve?");
        int noOfTimes = Integer.parseInt(response); // answer from question
        String result= null;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < noOfTimes; counter++) {
            Random obj = new Random();
            int num1 = obj.nextInt(10);
            int num2 = obj.nextInt(10);
            int rand = num1 + num2;

            int answer = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1 + "+" +num2));
            if (answer == rand){
                result= "Correct";
            }else {
                result= "Incorrect";
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number you get inside of the loop should not be stored in the same variable as the one you use in your while(...) condition. In this case, you used ans. In the example below I have separate variables for the math answer and the number of times to iterate in the loop. Another problem you had is that you were not passing the result message to the showMessageDialog(..) method.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathQuiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random obj = new Random();
        String timesString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many problems would you like to solve?");
        int timesInt = Integer.parseInt(timesString); // answer from question
        int counter = 0; //counts total math problems

        while (counter != timesInt) {
            counter++;

            int num1 = obj.nextInt(10);
            int num2 = obj.nextInt(10);
            int rand = num1 + num2;

            String answerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1 + "+" +num2);
            int answerInt = Integer.parseInt(answerString);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answerInt == rand ? "Correct" : "Incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```